# Jqueryui autocomplete does not work inside a Bootstrap model

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use JqueryUI autocomplete inside Bootstrap modal, but it doesn't work:

```
<!-- This one Works -->
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="locationSelector">City: </label>
  <input id="locationSelector">
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#citySelectionModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal (the autocomplete does not work here) -->
<div class="modal fade" id="citySelectionModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="citySelectionModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="citySelectionModalLabel">Select city</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="ui-widget">
          <label for="locationSelector">City: </label>
          <input id="locationSelector">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Clear</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Js code:

```
$(function() {
  var locationList = ['London', 'Bilbao', 'Paris', 'Madrid', 'Moscow', 'Berlin'];
  $("#locationSelector").autocomplete({
    source: locationList
  });
});
```

I recreated an example in jsfiddle: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/dh4e49z7/2/)

After some research, I think it is related to the modal contents being hidden, but I don't know how to solve it. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you try with jquery dialog instead of using boostrap modal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should edit you **css** and add your autocomplete higher `z-index` because bootstrap `.modal` class has `z-index: 1050;` so that you could even see the autocomplete any higher number than 1050 should do it

```
.ui-autocomplete {
  z-index: 1060;
}
```

Secondly you can't use same IDs in the same page. One way to fix it would be to change

> id -> class

Change your **HTML** `input` fields from `id="locationSelector"` to `class="locationSelector"` and change **JS** jQuery selector from `$("#locationSelector")` to `$(".locationSelector")`.

I also provided a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/dh4e49z7/33/

Answer (score 0):

your input field have same ids (locationSelector)

```
<div class="ui-widget">
 <label for="locationSelector">City: </label>
 <input id="locationSelector">
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="modal-body">
 <div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="locationSelector">City: </label>
  <input id="locationSelector">
 </div>
</div>
```

if same page has multiple same ids on different input fields it will not work.

Comment: It is just an example to show that it does work outside the modal. If I remove the first modal (the outsider), it still does not work

Comment: It seems like your jquery version is 3.2.1 change it to jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.9.2. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS below:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    z-index: 4000 !important;
}
```